# How to use JScrollpane within the CENTER of a BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have the following code:

```
    package example;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

    public class ScrollingExample extends JFrame
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            ScrollingExample scrollingExample = new ScrollingExample();
            scrollingExample.go();
        }

        private void go()
        {
            JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
            topPanel.add(new JLabel("boo"));

            JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
            JPanel mainInnerPanel = makeMainInnerPanel();

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mainInnerPanel);
            mainPanel.add(scrollPane);
            add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            pack();
            setVisible(true);
        }

        private JPanel makeMainInnerPanel()
        {
            JPanel row1 = makeHorizontalPanel("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
            JPanel row2 = makeHorizontalPanel("six", "seven", "eight");
            JPanel row3 = makeHorizontalPanel("nine", "ten", "eleven");
            JPanel mainInnerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            mainInnerPanel.add(row1);
            mainInnerPanel.add(row2);
            mainInnerPanel.add(row3);
            return mainInnerPanel;
        }

        private JPanel makeHorizontalPanel(String ... labelValues)
        {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            for (String s : labelValues)
            {
                JLabel label = new JLabel(s);
                panel.add(label);
            }
            return panel;
        }
    }
```

When I display it, it sizes itself to show all the labels; when I resize the window, I can't get scrollbars to show up.

When I get this working, I want to make a panel that contains a JTabbedPane and a couple of buttons, and I want THAT to have scroll bars if the user sizes the window so that some part of it cannot be seen.  If the answer to this question needs something additional or different to do that, mentioning it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class ScrollingExample extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ScrollingExample scrollingExample = new ScrollingExample();
        scrollingExample.go();
    }

    private void go()
    {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("boo"));

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel mainInnerPanel = makeMainInnerPanel();

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mainInnerPanel);
        mainPanel.add(scrollPane);
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel makeMainInnerPanel()
    {
        JPanel row1 = makeHorizontalPanel("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
        JPanel row2 = makeHorizontalPanel("six", "seven", "eight");
        JPanel row3 = makeHorizontalPanel("nine", "ten", "eleven");
        JPanel mainInnerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        mainInnerPanel.add(row1);
        mainInnerPanel.add(row2);
        mainInnerPanel.add(row3);
        return mainInnerPanel;
    }

    private JPanel makeHorizontalPanel(String ... labelValues)
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        for (String s : labelValues)
        {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(s);
            panel.add(label);
        }
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Comment: @mKorbel  I was actually about to delete my answer after (it took me 10 minutes to post &) I noticed yours was already there.  It's all good. :)

Comment: So evidently it was just FlowLayout on the panel that was to be scrolled.  Did I miss anything else?

Comment: Not that I can see.  Either a `BorderLayout` (with `CENTER` constraint) or `GridLayout` works to 'stretch the child to the size needed'.

Comment: Many thanks.  Since I wanted my panel to stick to the left rather than be centered, and I was putting a tabbedPane in the stretchable panel, I found that putting it in the WEST of a(nother) BorderLayout did that for me.  Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 5):

You need to allow the scrollpane to grow/shrink as the window size changes.

There is no need for the "mainPanel".

Just use:

```
// add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 3):

JPanel has by default [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html), you have to define that exactly (if you want to change [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)), JComponent have got implemented various LayoutManagers e.g. [JFrame / JDialog /JWindow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) (from Java5) has [Borderlayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) by default

```
mainPanel.setLayout(new Borderlayout(10, 10))
```

Comment: I don't think I want mainPanel to have BorderLayout -- I want the frame to have borderLayout, and mainPanel to go in the center of the frame.  FlowLayout should be all right for the Panel in the center, the one that I want resized when the frame resizes, shouldn't it?

Comment: `I want the frame to have borderLayout` ---> JFrame has by default BorderLayout, only put `myFrame.add(whatever, Borderlayout.CENTER)`, `FlowLayout ..... I want resized when the frame resizes` ---> FlowLayout will be ignore for JFrame resizing

Comment: Ok, if I set mainPanel to BoxLayout, THEN the scrollbars show up.  Do scrollbars not work on FlowLayout panels?  Is that written down somewhere that I missed?  Are there other layout managers for which it doesn't work?  It's great to have examples, but to understand what's going on, it would be great to (also) have conceptual principles to follow when doing something that none of the examples cover...